# phpcs possible raw SQL statement

Tags: magento2, php, database

In my code I've got a

`$connection->query("TRUNCATE TABLE $tableName");`

Works great. However using the official https://github.com/magento/magento-coding-standard ruleset it showed the following warning.

> Possible raw SQL satement.

Which I understand because it is.

My question is: is it possible to truncate a table within Magento without using raw SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `$connection->truncateTable($table)`

`\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql`

Comment: You know where I can find this method?

Comment: It's from class `\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql`